# Is there a way to copy a file automatically when exported or commited with GIT?

Tags: git

I sometimes build plugins for Godot. And the way their asset library works is you setup your `.gitattributes` to only output the addons folder:

```
/**        export-ignore
/addons    !export-ignore
/addons/** !export-ignore
```

But in their recommendations, they want you to include the `README` & `LICENSE` inside your plugin.

What I want is to be able to copy the `README` & `LICENSE` automatically. Kind of like the `export-ignore`.

I know that I could probably setup a Symbolic Link, but would prefer not to.

Comment: You can use the git commit hook function.

Comment: @LF00 This looks to be a good option. It would be nice to know in which hook to do this process.